# Algorithm - how to calculate the time complexity when an if statement is involved

Tags: algorithm

I am new to algorithm and have a question on how to calculate the time complexity when if statement is there. I have a priority queue implemented in heap. Here is the dequeue method:

```
int[] pQueue;
int length; 
int dequeue()
{
     int node = 1;
     int value = pQueue[--length];
     int maxValue = pQueue[node];

     int location = sift(node * 2, value);
     pQueue[location] = value;
     return maxValue;
}

int sift(int node, int value){
     if (node <= length){
         if (node < length && pQueue[node] < pQueue[node + 1])
         node++;
     if (value < pQueue[node]){
         pQueue[node / 2] = pQueue[node];
         return sift(node * 2, value);
         }
}
     return node / 2;
}
```

In the sift method, there are two lines of code:

```
         if (node < length && pQueue[node] < pQueue[node + 1])
         node++;
```

Since n++ is executed based on the condition above, should I count it or not when deriving the recurrence equation? I know that it does make any difference asymptotically, but is there any standard way of doing it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Processing the condition would probably take more time than doing the increment, calculating the time complexity does not make much sense to me. I would better calculate the complexity in terms of iterations if this is an option.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way is to take the condition into account when it depends on the variable under consideration. For example, consider a simple recursive function that calls itself inside an `if` statement:

```
double factorial(int n) {
    double result = n;
    if (n > 0) {
        result *= factorial(n - 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

If we pretend that the `if`-condition is always met, then the recursion is unbounded, and the complexity is infinite (regardless of *n*). If we pretend that the `if`-condition is never met, then the recursive call never happens, and the complexity is constant. Obviously, neither of these is an acceptable pretense; the complexity is in fact O(*n*).

When the condition does *not* depend on the variable under consideration, then the standard way is generally to give a worst-case complexity (and to indicate that we are doing so). For example, with sorting algorithms we typically give the complexity in terms of the length of the sequence being sorted, but many sorting algorithms perform differently depending on the initial ordering of elements. So, we assume that we are interested in their performance for sequences with the *least* favorable ordering for their length, and calculate accordingly.

(It's often also possible to provide an *average-case complexity*, however, by averaging across all possible inputs, and sometimes even a *typical-case complexity*.)

Answer (score 0):

Find the upper bound for the worst case. Each line before sift() calls 1 time. All instructions inside of sift() require constant time except the recursion call:

return sift(node * 2, value);

That particular line has a maximum amount of recursive calls determine by n. Specifically, it will call itself until node exceeds n–1 (node <= length, recalling that length decremented by 1). Bear in mind node doubles each time it recursively calls. Therefore, node doubles a number of times until it exceeds n thus it calls lg(n) times. That represents the worst case where value is the least element in pQueue’s heap subtrees. Now, to your point.

Since the recursion calls constant Θ(1) instructions O(lg(n)) times, you should really not concern yourself with the constants in the recursion equation because all of it sums together under Θ(1):

T(n) = O(lg(n)) + Θ(1)